# Secured API Key not extending filter of it's parent API Key for User-restricted access

Tags: algolia

My algolia index `creatorUid` which either has the `PRESET_EXPORTER`. Everybody should be allowed to read the `PRESET_EXPORTER` documents. Additionally users should only be allowed to read their own documents (where `creatorUid` is the user's id).

Therefore, I created an API Key with the query parameter `filters=(creatorUid:PRESET_EXPORTER)`.

This API Key works as intended, it allows to search for `PRESET_EXPORTER` documents.

Additionally, for each user I create their own secured API Key like this:

```
const originalApiKey = '3398a693e444dd393fd84c80824fd6a9';
const filters = `(creatorUid:PRESET_EXPORTER OR creatorUid:${uid})`;
const securedApiKey = client.generateSecuredApiKey(originalApiKey, { filters });

console.log(securedApiKey);
```

However, I can't load the documents where the user's id matches the `creatorUid`.

Interestingly, when I edit my parent Search Key to use the query parameter `filters=(creatorUid:PRESET_EXPORTER OR creatorUid:rYdMeaLPvsXO6YqU0iuwdVTrhyS2)` it does work as intended. This must mean that something with the secured API Key does not work.

Any ideas where the issue could be?